# Wifi Hotspot problems with wifi driver

Tags: wifi, hotspot

I’m trying to get a wifi hotspot set up on the Pi and am using the [Broadcom Wi-Fi Adapter with USB hub](http://www.broadcom.com/blog/raspberry-pi/want-wi-fi-for-your-raspberry-pi-broadcom-adapter-brings-connectivity-with-less-power/). I'm not sure what driver to put in hostapd.conf file, any help would be great. This is what I have in there at the moment:

```
interface=wlan0
*driver=rtl8192*
ssid=PI_ROUTER
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

...and this is the error I get:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Line 2: invalid/unknown driver 'rtl8192  '
1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
```

Comment: http://www.daveconroy.com/turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-hotspot-with-edimax-nano-usb-ew-7811un-rtl8188cus-chipset/ is a similar module to what you have and could be of help.

Comment: run `lsusb` with the adapter plugged in. Sometimes manufacturers change chipsets and don't tell anybody. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the driver `nl80211`. If that doesn't work, remove or comment out the line altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to check the drivers supported by Linux. This is the website you can find more information: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers.

Where as rtl8192ce has a support, its possible to configure at hostapd conf.

You need to set up with correct name of driver, something like this.

{code}
driver=rtl8192ce
{code}

If this didn't solve the problem then install sudo apt-get install libssl-dev it will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using wheezey checkout the instructions at coderbot.org or simplesi.net i have used them in the past and managed to create a hotspot.

I am struggling to create a hotspot using jessie.

Answer (score 1):

If all the other advice fails, try Ubuntu-Mate.  I had 4 usb wifi adapters, two of which were advertised to have worked with my Raspberry Pi 2.  Although all 4 adapters found my wifi hotspot, none would even attempt to connect to any of the strong hotspots it found.   That was using the latest Rasbarian (Debian-Jessie).

Then I created another micro-sd bootup card, with Ubuntu-Mate.  On the First Boot, I clicked my wifi-hotspot, plugged in the password, and BINGO -- IT WORKED!!   And, my HDMI-sound also instantly worked, whereas before hand I couldn't get that to work either.  I don't know if any of the troubles had to do with me being in the USA, and perhaps Raspbarian not does not work well for unknown reasons.  But Ubuntu-Mate had ZERO Problems.

I'm guessing all the Raspberry Pies have enough power to boot Ubuntu-Mate, connect to WiFi from the desktop, and run the terminal shell -- BASH

Comment: Thanks for the feed back ill give it ago as soon as i can. sorry for the well over due response go distracted by other projects